# Compact form of a bash file extension test condition

Tags: bash, syntax

I am testing whether arguments are not video files (`.mp4`, `.mkv`).  Can I clean this so as to make it more compact test.

```
if [[ ! "$1" == *.mp4 || ! "$1" == *.mkv ]]; then
```

Comment: Check that logic, I think you mean `if ! [[ "$1" == *.mp4 || "$1" == *.mkv ]]`.

Comment: You might be correct about the wrong logic.  Have been using `if [[ ! "$1" =~ (\.mp4|\.mkv)$ ]]; then`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a [case](/questions/tagged/case) statement is simpler and more portable (does not rely on Bash-specific syntax):

```bash
#!/bin/sh
case $1 in
    *.mp4|*.mkv) ;;
    *) echo "not a video file" ;;
esac
```